# How do include TIME with my SQL query for finding data between two dates?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get data between two dates that should include seconds

I'm currently using the below code, which works fine; however now it needs to be more precise to include the time.

```
where h.creation_time >= date '2017-01-01'
and h.CLOSED_TIME >= date '2018-12-16' and h.CLOSED_TIME <= date '2018-12-17'
```

Here is what I tried changing the code to:

```
where (h.creation_time >= date '2017-01-01')
and (h.CLOSED_TIME between '2018-12-16 18:19:00' and '2018-12-16 18:20:00')
```

I should expect the results of everything between 6:19pm and 6:20pm (one minute time frame). Instead it is spitting out the error:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: what datatype are the values stored in?

Comment: @javan.rajpopat they are stored as type DATE

Comment: it should be in the data type DATETIME or TIMESTAMP to compare it by Time and Date.

Comment: The issue is that the `DATE` literal is for calendar dates only, it does not take a time-of-day component. The `TIMESTAMP` literal would do what you need; do not remove the keyword `DATE`, but instead **replace** it with `TIMESTAMP`. This has one disadvantage though - it relies on implicit conversion between `date` and `timestamp` data types. It may be best to use `TO_DATE()` with the appropriate format model, in this case `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'`.

Comment: Question though - `between a and b` means `>= a and <= b`. If you use this for consecutive intervals, the endpoints will be double counted. The common (and correct) solution is to avoid the keyword `between` and to write the inequalities explicitly as `>= a and < b` - with *strict* inequality for the upper end point.

Comment: One more note about using `TIMESTAMP` literals...  definitely DON'T use that solution if you have a lot of data and the `CLOSED_TIME` column is indexed; if you use the `TIMESTAMP` approach, the column values must be converted to timestamp, and that kills the ability to use the index. :-(

Comment: @mathguy Unless the data type is `timestamp` (this isn't specified).  Use `to_date()` if the column is `date` and use `to_timestamp()` if the column is `timestamp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert them explicitly with `to_date()`.

```
WHERE h.creation_time >= to_date('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      AND h.closed_time BETWEEN to_date('2018-12-16 18:19:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                                AND to_date('2018-12-16 18:20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: This seemed to be the best solution considering how much date I do have, thank you for your quick feedback!

Answer (score 2):

A timestamp literal starts with the keyword `TIMESTAMP` (just as a date literal starts with `DATE`):

```
where h.creation_time >= date '2017-01-01'
and h.closed_time between timestamp '2018-12-16 18:19:00' and timestamp '2018-12-16 18:20:00'
```

In order to take fractions of seconds into account, you shouldn't use `BETWEEN` however, but:

```
where h.creation_time >= date '2017-01-01'
and h.closed_time >= timestamp '2018-12-16 18:19:00' 
and h.closed_time < timestamp '2018-12-16 18:20:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

> everything between 6:19pm and 6:20pm (one minute time frame)

The problem presented here is not only technical but lingual. The word "between" can have several subtle differences such as **driving between the gateposts** (i..e hopefully that car does not hit either side and so no gatepost is included) or **flying between London and Paris** where both cities are included otherwise you have fallen short of the destination.

SQL standards use the latter approach for between, it is defined as inclusive of both endpoints. This is a potential problem for date/time ranges as it can lead to double-counting of endpoints. As @mathguy indicates in his excellent comment under the question the stricter approach is to **avoid using between** and explicitly define the range this way:

```
WHERE h.creation_time >= to_date('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND h.closed_time >= to_date('2018-12-16 18:19:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND h.closed_time  < to_date('2018-12-16 18:20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

IF the `closed_time` column is a `date` data type use `to_date()`

IF the `closed_time` column is a `timestamp` data type use `to_timestamp()` instead.